# treeView1_NodeMouseClick method for left click event in an array of nodes

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

I have created a custom windows form and I have emdeded a TreeView. I have specific parent/children nodes in the TreeView. Although, for certain nodes, I want to create different children nodes according to an output array from an application programming interface that I develop. For instance, if my output is an array of length = 2, I want to create 2 children nodes in the first children node. Up to this point, I have successfully managed to carry out this task. However, when I am trying to connect my children nodes when left clicking with different methods, my program crashes.

I attach a part of my code with some explanation:

```cs
   public partial class FeatureTree : Form
{


    public TreeNode rootRootChildren01, rootRootChildren02;
    public object[] rootRootChildren;
    public TreeNode rootNode;
    public TreeNode rootChildNode01, rootChildNode02;


    public FeatureTree(AddinClass addin)
    {
        userAddin = addin;
        App = (api)userAddin.Application;
        InitializeComponent();
        PopulateTreeView();
        this.treeView1.MouseDown += new MouseEventHandler(treeView1_MouseDown);
        this.treeView1.NodeMouseClick += new TreeNodeMouseClickEventHandler(this.treeView1_NodeMouseClick);
    }

    public void PopulateTreeView()
    {
        // Clear the TreeView each time the method is called.
        treeView1.Nodes.Clear();

        rootNode = new TreeNode("Parent Node 1");
        rootChildNode01 = new TreeNode("Child1");
        rootChildNode02 = new TreeNode("Child2");
        // Parent root
        treeView1.Nodes.Add(rootNode);
        // firts children root 
        rootNode.Nodes.Add(rootChildNode01);

        // here I check whether the output array is nothing
        if (userAddin.outputArray != null)
        {
            // if the output is not null create userAddin.outputArray.Length children roots
            rootRootChildren = new object[userAddin.outputArray.Length];
            for (int i = 0; i < userAddin.outputArray.Length; i++)
            {

                rootRootChildren[i] = new TreeNode(userAddin.beasyShell[i].Name);
                rootChildNode01.Nodes.Add((TreeNode)rootRootChildren[i]);

            }
            rootRootChildren01 = (TreeNode)rootRootChildren[0];
            rootRootChildren02 = (TreeNode)rootRootChildren[1];
        }

        // second children root
        rootNode.Nodes.Add(rootChildNode02);

        treeView1.ShowPlusMinus = false;
        treeView1.ExpandAll();
        treeView1.ShowNodeToolTips = true;
    }

    void treeView1_NodeMouseClick(object sender, TreeNodeMouseClickEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Node == rootRootChildren01 && e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {

            userAddin.method_1;

        }
        if (e.Node == rootRootChildren02 && e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {

            userAddin.method_2;

        }

    }
```

The above code works pretty well. However, how could I set in the treeView1_NodeMouseClick method the right click event according to the rootRootChildren array? For this occasion only two nodes are created. But what if the output array is much bigger?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Thanks Hans. So if I get this node, how could I connect the click event with a method? Could you please give me an example? I am not very experienced NET programmer.

Comment: Ok, ignore my previous comment. I found out that there is the e.node.index method with the e.node.parent that does the trick.